# how to enable CDC in google cloud sql server for AWS DMS replication?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, aws-dms, amazon-aurora

I am trying to migrate data from GCP cloud sql server to AWS aurora MySQL using DMS CDC, for this I need to enable CDC on DMS source database which cloud SQL. As per the AWS documentation I need to enable CDC by executing "sp_cdc_enable_db" SP and for this I need sysadmin access but google cloud doesn't support sysadmin access. So, in this scenario how to enable CDC?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As you know, Cloud SQL doesn't support sysadmin access, and [CDC feature](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/features#sqlserver-unavailable) too.

So you have to use different method to the migration process.

If you really want to use CDC, I recommend to use middle-man replication between GCP cloud sql and AWS aurora mysql.

Just replicate your cloud sql to on-premise or somewhere else where you can execute cdc.

And then migrate the SQL server replication to AWS aurora using AWS DMS, But aurora will not be synced with source DB in cloud sql.

Or if you just want to both DBs are in sync, Have you tried steps AWS document described in [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/sbs/CHAP_SQLServer2Aurora.Steps.ConfigureSQLServer.html)?

I think "Migrating existing data and replicating ongoing changes" section worked exactly you want.

Comment: Thank you for the response and Idea. For sure we are not going with middle-man approach as it adds extra headache. Even for the MS-REPLICATION need to enable the distribution and for this also we need sysadmin role right? Because when I am trying to configure distribution, seeing this error "You must be a member of the sysadmin fixed server role to complete this operation."

Comment: Then you can't use AWS DMS syncronization feature in this situation. IMO, It is much simpler method to migrate existing data only and then load incoming data into AWS aurora.